# create new row from existing row bash

Tags: awk

I have a csv file with below data.

```
name,mem,125,165,589,458
name1,mem1,154,544,485,456
```

I want to modify the file like below.

```
name,mem,125,165
name,mem,589,458
name1,mem1,154,544
name1,mem1,485,456
```

Is there any simple and efficient way to achieve this, maybe by using awk?
here `125 - 165, 589 - 458, & 154-544, 485 - 456` are pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat input
name,mem,125,165,589,458
name1,mem1,154,544,485,456
$ awk '{for(i = 3; i < NF; i+=2) printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$i,$(i+1))}' FS=, input
name,mem,125,165
name,mem,589,458
name1,mem1,154,544
name1,mem1,485,456
```

As for "modifying the file", don't.  Redirect your output to a different file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk.

`-F` sets the field separator

The awk program loops over the fields 3 to NF for every row and prints the first two fields followed by the current field in the for loop. (NF is a predefined variable that holds the number of fields per row.)

```
awk -F',' '{for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $1,$2,$i}' input.csv
```

Comment: edited question, I needed a result like that, is it possible with awk?